# how to deal with embedded interfaces and share data between them

Tags: oop, go, interface

I would like to better understand how to use interfaces, mainly to split code in reusable components and at the same time make it more easy for testing, currently my main question is how to share/get data between the interfaces that belong to a main interface, for example:

https://play.golang.org/p/67CQor1_pY

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MainInterface interface {
    SubInterfaceA
    SubInterfaceB
}

type SubInterfaceA interface {
    MethodA()
    GetterA(s implementMain)
}

type SubInterfaceB interface {
    MethodB()
    GetterB(s implementMain)
}

type implementA struct{}

func (ia *implementA) MethodA() { fmt.Println("I am method A") }
func (ia *implementA) GetterA(s implementMain) {
    fmt.Println(s.Data)
}

type implementB struct{}

func (ib *implementB) MethodB() { fmt.Println("I am method B") }
func (ib *implementB) GetterB(s implementMain) {
    fmt.Println(s.Data)
}

type implementMain struct {
    Data string
    SubInterfaceA
    SubInterfaceB
}

func New(d string) implementMain {
    return implementMain{
        Data:          d,
        SubInterfaceA: &implementA{},
        SubInterfaceB: &implementB{},
    }
}

func main() {
    var m MainInterface

    m = New("something")

    fmt.Println(m.(implementMain).Data)

    m.MethodA()                  // prints I am method A
    m.MethodB()                  // prints I am method B
    m.GetterA(m.(implementMain)) // prints "something"
    m.GetterB(m.(implementMain)) // prints "something"
}
```

In the above code, within the methods of struct `implementA` or `implementB` how to  access the struct elements of the parent holder  `implementMain` that implements `MainInterface` without passing it  as an argument?

with holder struct I mean:

```
type implementMain struct {
    Data string
    SubInterfaceA
    SubInterfaceB
}
```

If I am right `SubInterfaceA` and `SubInterfaceB` are embedded and help to make the struct `implementMain` satisfy the `MainInterface`:

```
type MainInterface interface {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   SubInterfaceA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   SubInterfaceB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
}
```

But within the embedded methods of the `SubInterfaceA` or `subInterfaceB` what is the best practice to use in order to be available to get the `data string`?

I created `Getter(s implementMain)` method and passed the **holder** struct, but had to cast type:

```
m.GetterA(m.(implementMain))
```

I don't know if by satisfying a interface, all the involved interfaces can become part of the same structure scope and if they do, how to get/share data between them or either between its components?, for example besides been available to reach `data string` how from `SubInterfaceA` get/access `SubInterfaceB`

Comment: I think you're confusing embedding with inheritance here. There's no way to access the "parent" struct, without passing it as a parameter like any other (and the receiver itself is a parameter). Embedding interfaces is simply declaring that you're going to satisfy those interfaces.

Comment: @JimB  is there a better way of doing this ``m.GetterA(m.(implementMain))`` basically in the example I post, if I want to access data from an outer/parent I need to pass it as a reference, like you describe but I have to use type assertion, it works but just wondering if there is a better way of doing this

Comment: I would really advise you to try to compose this differently. I can't imagine what you're trying to solve, but this looks like an attempt at inheritance-based OOP in Go. If it helps, one would normally operate on the struct value rather than the interface value, and let it be converted to an interface only as needed: https://play.golang.org/p/9H9z9qoLcc, but this circular dependency is usually not a good idea.

Comment: @JimB I was trying to test something and found this post http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2015/10/10/interfaces-and-composition-for-effective-unit-testing-in-golang/ in where basically operates at a interface level rather than struct and is what confused me

Comment: operating on interfaces is fine, and allows you to plug in other implementations, but interfaces themselves aren't your problem here. The base of the problem is the circular dependency between the embedded value and the outer value. Why doesn't `implementMain` implement it's own method for fetching `data`? If `SubInterfaceB` needs to operate on that, have the outer method chain the call and provide the value.

Comment: @JimB thank for the comments, Is more clear for me now, basically if I am right, while operating on interfaces and depending on the required data, could be the case that more methods setters/getters would be needed